# swift: best class design with closures to avoid strong reference cycles

Tags: design-patterns, swift

Suppose you have two classes. The first class has a bunch of small functions that typically used in combination with each other. Because these functions need to access a shared resource, it's more efficient to group them together.

To call the small functions, you need a reference to the class. There are two ways to get this.

```
class FirstClass
{
  // lots of small functions
  ...
  func doWork(){}

  //group function that takes a closure
  func transactionsA(workUnit : ()->(NSError?)) -> NSError?
  {
      //obtain access to shared resource
      ...    
      //do work 
      workUnit()
      //close access to shared resource
      ...   
  }

  func transactionsB(workUnit : (let instanceOfFirstClass)->(NSError?)) -> NSError?
  {
      //obtain access to shared resource
      ...    
      //do work 
      workUnit(self)    
      //close access to shared resource
      ...   
  }
}


class SecondClass
{
  let instanceOfFirstClass =  FirstClass()

  //first approach
  func doGroupWorkA()
  {
     instanceOfFirstClass.transactionsA() {[unowned self] () -> (Error?) in
        self.instanceOfFirstClass.doWork()
     }
   }

  //second approach
  func doGroupWorkA()
  {
     instanceOfFirstClass.transactionsB() {[unowned self] 
      (let  instanceOfFirstClass) -> (Error?) in
        //do the actual work via the smaller functions
        instanceOfFirstClass.doWork()
     }
   }

}
```

In the first approach you just call the functions via self.instanceOfFirstClass, but in the second approach you obtain the instance as a parameter of the closure.

There is probably not much difference but which approach is better? Is there a risk of creating reference cycles?

My concrete use case is a small SQLite wrapper.

**Edit:** to expand upon my particular use case, although I think the question and answer should be broader than that:

FirstClass is a SQLite wrapper. It talks directly to the database (open/close connection, create/prepare/bind SQL queries like fetch and insert).

SecondClass can be any class that needs to store or retrieve data. To take advantage of transactions, I need to group my queries. DoWork() would be something like begin transaction, loop(fetch, process, insert), commit/end transaction.

The transaction functions also open and close the database connection when appropriate. This avoids that the connection remains open but idle for the entire duration of the application or lifetime of the document.

Should an error occur, the transaction is rolled back and the connection is closed.

Comment: The question is confusing, but it feels like you're reinventing `dispatch_queue` (specifically serial queues) and `dispatch_group`. It's not clear how you make use of the returned errors, which has a big impact on what patterns make sense. Currently my preferred approach to this general class of problem in Swift is a Future object (for example: https://github.com/LlamaKit/LlamaKit/blob/a4de305580966b0c6efd9ad4181be4a7099c13cf/LlamaKit/Future.swift), but I'm not certain that's applicable because I'm not quite clear how you're using FirstClass and SecondClass.

Comment: No, I am not using queues directly in these classes. All of this work already happens on a private queue anyway. And since it's all serial work there is little point to have an additional serial dispatch_queue.

Dispatch_group with _enter, _leave and _wait is nice when the work can be serialised. That is not the case when talking to a shared resource such as here.

I am not entirely sure what your Future class does. It looks like an async queue with callbacks?

Comment: The point of the Future class is to represent the future value of a computation that might fail. You can apply additional computations on it that will be performed when it completes (or automatically skipped if it fails). Regarding queues, since queues can target other queues, and queues can be suspended pending getting all of their blocks in place (which itself can be managed with groups), GCD provides powerful tools for what you're describing when used for more than the introductory "run something on the background."

Comment: But to your deeper question, my recommendation is to copy the actual data you need out of `self` into a immutable structure that you put into processing. That gets rid of all the retain loop awkwardness that I think you're running into. Think of these operations as pure functions, and put them into operations (even `NSOperation` ideally), rather than trying to interact with an object like `self`.

Comment: I have done a few things with GCD, but never targeting other queues. Time to start up a toy project. :)

But self is the object initiating the processing. self (i.e. firstObject) has a function that takes a closure. The closure does some work but in order to do so needs to call functions of self.

And why wouldn't I want to interact with self? It's just the local instance object. That is like saying don't call functions on an instance of another class.

Anyway, both approaches work (in my limited testing). Just wanted to know which one was the proper way.